# Sum of array in php, array generated from excel file

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading excel file in php. I want to show the total of one column in the last row. To do that I need to get the total sum of below array.

part of code to get the below array is,

Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 )

```
$file = "$filename";
$sheet = (isset($_POST['sheet'])) ? $_POST['sheet'] : '';
$connection = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$connection->read($file);   

echo"<table>";
$x = 1;
while ($x <= $connection->sheets[$sheet]['numRows']) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    $y=1;
    while ($y <= $connection->sheets[$sheet]['numCols']) {
        $cell = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][$y]) ?  $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
        echo "\t\t<td>$cell</td>\n";  
        $y++;
    }  
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
    $x++;
}
$x = 2;
while ($x <= $connection->sheets[$sheet]['numRows']) {
    $ctnqty = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][16]) ?    
    $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][16] : '';
    $ctnqtyttl = explode(",",$ctnqty);
    print_r ($ctnqtyttl);
    $x++;
}
```

I'm suing below code to get the sum of above array, but its giving me the result of 2 only. Please help me here to get the sum 3.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($ctnqtyttl as $value) {
    echo $sum = $sum + $value;
}
```

Comment: It really helps to read and understand code (even for yourself) when you have it properly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ctnqtyttl` is overwritten each time with a new value in your second `while` loop, so it forgets any previous values. The sum you calculate will only be based on the last value it has.

Skip the final `foreach` loop, and calculate the sum during the second `while` loop as follows:

```
$sum = 0; // <-------
$x = 2;
while ($x <= $connection->sheets[$sheet]['numRows']) {
    $ctnqty = isset($connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][16]) ?    
                    $connection->sheets[$sheet]['cells'][$x][16] : '';
    $ctnqtyttl = explode(",", $ctnqty);
    print_r ($ctnqtyttl);
    $sum += array_sum($ctnqtyttl); // <-------
    $x++;
}
```